# How can I reduce Source Games load times, specifically Half-Life 2?

Tags: technical-issues, performance, half-life-2

These games takes like 30-60 seconds to load a new section, depending on how many assets need to be loaded

Any way to decrease these load times? 10 seconds would feel like heaven, any help appreciated.

Specs:

- CPU - AMD Ryzen 3 3100
- Graphics Card - AMD Radeon RX 550/500 Series
- RAM - 16 GB
- SSD - 1 TB